# Is there an equivalent to #implementedBySubclass in Java?

Tags: java, oop, smalltalk

I have a design question. I have a class hierarchy:

- AbstractEntity
- NPC extends AbstractEntity implements LifeForm
- Player extends AbstractEntity implements LifeForm

There is a method #moveTo(Target target).
This method exists currently in both Player and NPC.

The implemetation is the same for both classes.
Only one method called (getQueuedActions()) has a different implementation.

So, in theory, the whole method can be implemented at AbstractEntity, and the concrete difference is implemented at the child class level.
But the Java compiler says: getQueuedActions() needs to be implemented also at AbstractEntity.
I could of course do an instace of check and implement accordinly. But I thought I ask here, for I think I have something wrong here.

Is there a way to implement the method in Java indicating that yes, this does exist at AbstractEntity but look at the concrete (sub-)class for the real implementation?
In Smalltalk, you would do ^implementedBySubClass.
To explain, #implementedBySubClass is a way of defining a method as abstract at one level of the class hierarchy but still support a certain protocol (or interface) while not having a real implementation.

Is there an equivalent in Java?

Comment: Can you show some code? For example, what code makes the compiler say "getQueuedActions() needs to be implemented also at AbstractEntity"?

Comment: If the Java compiler is saying that you need it, then you almost certainly have things organized so that it _isn't_ actually implemented, and you _do_ need to do some different arranging of things.  If you showed us some code, we could probably identify the issue.

Comment: Please note that the selector that most Smalltalk dialects use for the message you are looking for is `#subclassResponsibility`.

Comment: To confirm the assumptions of some answers: yes, #subclassResponsibility and probably #implementedBySubclass are the equivalent of marking a method as abstract in languages like Java.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia Smalltalk has been some time ago, thank you for correcting me.  In VS(E) it really was called Object>>#implementedBySubclass.

Comment: @JayK thank you so much, this is exactly what I was missing.
Its been years since I have done proper development for one and the distinction between abstract class and concrete method and abstract method was lost on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you put `moveTo(Target)` in `AbstractEntity` that would mean **all** `AbstractEntity`es can be moved. All of them. You can't not: That's what putting it at that level means.

If NPC can be moved, and Player can be moved, but let's say Tree (also an `AbstractEntity`) cannot, then **`moveTo` should NOT be in `AbstractEntity` at all!**

Possibly you want something in between; perhaps `Person extends MovableEntity` and `NPC extends MovableEntity`, and `MovableEntity extends AbstractEntity`. And `moveTo` can go in `MovableEntity`.

Whether it's `MovableEntity` or `AbstractEntity` that gets a `moveTo(Target target)` method - you are free to specify an implementation or not (the act of saying: "All Xs have the Y method" is separate from "... and here is the code for that method". You choose: Either do the first (decree that the method must be there, but not what the code for it is), or both (decree that the method must be there, *and* provide an implementation, which a subclass is free to override with an alternate implementation unless you want to disable that, which you can, by marking the method with the `final` keyword).

That implementation is free to use any other property of the type it is in - including properties that are of the 'The type decrees this property exists, not what it looks like' variety. This is perfectly legal java:

```
class MovableEntity extends AbstractEntity {
  public void moveTo(Target target) {
    var actions = getQueuedActions();
    .... move to and do the actions ....
  }

  public abstract List<Action> getQueuedActions();
}
```

This class definition says:

- You can't instantiate me; I am abstract. My only reason for existing is to serve as common supertype for other more specific types. If nobody ever writes `class Something extends MovableEntity`, this code is completely useless.
- All `MovableEntity` instances regardless of its actual type have a `moveTo(Target)` method, as well as a `getQueuedActions` method. A subclass can't 'remove' this.
- Any types that `extends` MovableEntity **must** provide an implementation of the `getQueuedActions` method - failure to do so is a compiler error. Unless they are marked `abstract` which is fine (in which case the requirement to have that method is passed on to any subclasses of *it* in turn).
- Any types that `extends` MovableEntity **may** provide its own implementation of `moveTo(Target)` - even if it does, an impl of `getQueuedActions` must still be provided, that rule doesn't change. If it doesn't provide an implementation, it inherits the implementation as provided here (which ends up invoking `getQueuedActions` as part of how it works).

Possibly `^implementedBySubclass` is smalltalk-ese for marking a method as `abstract`. You should in general, when asking on SO questions in the vein of "This thing in language X - is there an equivalent to that in language Y?", explain what 'this thing' actually means.

*Especially* for Smalltalk: Documentation is hard to find.

Comment: The answer is sound, except for the unnecessary rant about Smalltalk. This paragraph is simply uninformed: the language is not dead, it did have many users in the past, the docs are freely accessible, even for some commercial Smalltalks, the companies like IBM, Instantiations, and Cincom are not bankrupt, also there exist open source Smalltalks. Also not the entire spec fits on the postcard, but just examples of most of the syntax elements of the language. The point that the asker could have explained how implementedBySubclass works is valid.

Comment: There is nothing special about the `subclassResponsibility` method in Smalltalk, it is just a regular method whose purpose is purely informative. Regarding the post-card story, it is a relatively modern marketing "idea" that the Smalltalk community never took seriously. Smalltalk is much more interesting than that.

Comment: Thank you, making the method abstract in #AbstractEntity did the trick. I was not aware of the difference that an abstract method in a class and a method in an abstract class is not the same.

Answer (score 3):

This is the difference between a *strongly-typed language* like Java and a *dynamically-typed language* like Smalltalk.

In **Smalltalk**, you can rely on convention to glue things together, and if something breaks, the developer needs to debug it and figure out why (they'd likely see an error with `#subclassResponsibility`).

**Java** needs to know at complile time what classes can or can't do. So in your case, it's complaining that you're expecting your abstract class to understand/implement a method, but only the subclasses understand it - and you could in future be adding other concrete subclasses whose instances don't implement the method.

So one approach you could take in Java would be to implement the method in the abstract superclass, but throw an exception - either a custom one, or something like `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. The subclasses can then override that method to provide their specific implementations. That way, each instance behaves correctly, and the compiler is happy. If you were to add a new concrete subclass that doesn't override the method, you'd get your exception at runtime if you tried to call that method - which would tell you that you need to implement it.

Comment: Throwing the "not implemented" exception in the abstract superclass is indeed the closest reproduction of the behavior of a "subclass responsibility" method in Smalltalk. Only that most Java environments do not offer you to add the method to the subclass on the spot when the debugger pops up on that exception.